# Using async await on custom promise

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

Im trying to use async await on a function that returns a promise but the out put im getting is **`Promise { <pending> }`**. In here im using function called convertFiletoPDF which returns a promise. I need to get the output (the path that i have mention in resolve() ).
When i use it as

```
convertFiletoPDF(file).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
}).catch((err)=>{
  console.log(err);
});
```

it gives the expected result.Whats wrong with the code below? im quite new to these async await and promises.

```
 function convertFiletoPDF(file) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    unoconv.convert(file, "pdf", function(
      err,
      result
    ) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      let File = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("/")+1,file.lastIndexOf("."));
      // result is returned as a Buffer
      fs.writeFile(__dirname+"/files/converted/"+File+".pdf", result, error => {
        /* handle error */
        if (err) reject(error);
        else resolve("./files/converted/"+File+".pdf");
      });
    });
  });
}

async function myfunc(file){
  let res = await convertFiletoPDF(file);
  return res;
}

let res = myfunc(file);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return value of an `async` function is a promise, so naturally that's what your `console.log` outputs. You need to either consume the result via `await` (within another `async` function, or at the top level of a module) or use `then`/`catch`.

This is what you're currently doing:

```js
function convertFiletoPDF(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 400, "Done");
    });
}

async function myfunc(file){
    let res = await convertFiletoPDF(file);
    return res;
}

let res = myfunc("some file");
console.log(res);
```

You need to be doing either this:

```js
function convertFiletoPDF(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 400, "Done");
    });
}

async function myfunc(file){
    let res = await convertFiletoPDF(file);
    return res;
}

// (In a module you wouldn't need this wrapper)
(async() => {
    try {
        let res = await myfunc("some file");
        console.log(res);
    } catch (e) {
        // Deal with the fact there was an error
    }
})();
```

or with `then` and `catch`:

```js
function convertFiletoPDF(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 400, "Done");
    });
}

async function myfunc(file){
    let res = await convertFiletoPDF(file);
    return res;
}

myfunc("some file")
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        // Deal with the fact there was an error
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
convertFiletoPDF()
```

This function run and returned a Promise. This is fine.

```
myfunc()
```

Lets say `myfunc` takes 10 seconds. Javascript starts to wait newly created thread result from `libuv` via `event loop` mechanism.  So, Javascript says, "That one is async, I will not wait, when it finishes it will let me know and i will run my `then` callback and then I will proceed with its output."

Javascript keeps his promise. Tries to run next below lines. `myFunch` is still working. Output is not ready yet. Returns undefined.

```
let res = myfunc(file);
console.log(res);
```

You get undefined.

Answer (score -1):

Someone might find this example from my code useful. You can wrap it in a promise and then resolve the custom promise and then call another promise to confirm the receipt of the original web3 call.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    tokenContract.methods.approve(
        exchangeAddress, 
        BIG_NUMBER_1e50
    )
    .send({ from })
    .once('transactionHash')
    .once('receipt', receipt => resolve(receipt))
    .on('confirmation')
    .on('error', err => reject(err))
    .then( receipt => // will be fired once the receipt its mined
        console.log(receipt),
    );
});
```